# Unable to connect to Raspberry Pi 3 B+ from MacBook Air through wire

Tags: connection, macos, ping

I am trying to establish a wired connection between my RPi 3 B+ and my MacBook Air. After I connected the two devices with a wire, my MacBook got IP=169.254.214.218, and my RPi got IP=10.0.0.21. When I pinged my RPi from my MacBook, ping recognized the name "realtimepi.local" (IP=10.0.0.21). However, the requests always went timeout. When I pinged my MacBook from my RPi, ping only occasionally recognized "<my MacBook's name>.local", so I pinged 169.254.214.218 directly. The requests always encountered the error "Destination Host Unreachable". I checked several related posts and ran some commands to diagnose this problem but in vain. The following is what I have known so far. Could someone share any thoughts/feedback? Thanks.

I found that my MacBook's IP indicated that the DHCP server is not reachable. I am unsure if this is the cause and why. On my MacBook, I have set "Configure IPv4: Using DHCP", "Location: Automatic", "Configure IPv6: Automatically", and "DNS Servers: 10.0.0.1, 10.10.10.10, ..., 8.8.8.8, ...".

My RPi has been configured to automatically search for and connect to my phone's Wi-Fi. My MacBook can then communicate with my RPi wirelessly. In this way, I ssh-logged into my RPi, ran `ifconfig`, `route -n`, `ip route ls`, and checked `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`.

```
pi@realtimepi:~ $ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.21  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::cebe:1e7a:d284:3733  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:01:cc:42  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 695  bytes 220566 (215.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 266  bytes 13230 (12.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 167  bytes 16130 (15.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 167  bytes 16130 (15.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.228  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        inet6 fe80::a639:4e7c:b4ef:f5e5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2607:fb90:6e2c:1057:abd:aa36:70c7:7123  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether b8:27:eb:54:99:17  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 811  bytes 90049 (87.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 476  bytes 72780 (71.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
pi@realtimepi:~ $ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
```

```
pi@realtimepi:~ $ ip route ls
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 src 10.0.0.21 metric 202 
default via 192.168.43.1 dev wlan0 src 192.168.43.228 metric 303 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.21 metric 202 
192.168.43.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.43.228 metric 303
```

part of `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`, the unlikely relevant lines omitted

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=10.0.0.21/24
static routers=10.0.0.1
static domain_name_servers=10.0.0.1 8.8.8.8

# interface eth0
#   nogateway
```

I also ran `ifconfig` on my MacBook.

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 48:bf:6b:d3:2f:de 
    inet6 fe80::1810:2058:e5a0:4491%en0 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x4 
    inet 192.168.43.173 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.43.255
    inet6 2607:fb90:6e2c:1057:4e6:3b53:93b:f117 prefixlen 64 autoconf secured 
    inet6 2607:fb90:6e2c:1057:15b5:d130:cc2b:1e16 prefixlen 64 autoconf temporary 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=460<TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 82:18:34:12:02:40 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8822<BROADCAST,SMART,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 82:18:34:12:02:40 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 0a:bf:6b:d3:2f:de 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 96:9e:70:32:fd:dd 
    inet6 fe80::949e:70ff:fe32:fddd%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x8 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
llw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 96:9e:70:32:fd:dd 
    inet6 fe80::949e:70ff:fe32:fddd%llw0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x9 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
utun0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1380
    inet6 fe80::1d3f:f1bc:8034:44e3%utun0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xa 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
utun1: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 2000
    inet6 fe80::bedd:ab54:da62:8d19%utun1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xb 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
en3: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=50b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,AV,CHANNEL_IO>
    ether a8:60:b6:00:77:85 
    inet6 fe80::834:760f:3480:a927%en3 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0xc 
    inet 169.254.214.218 netmask 0xffff0000 broadcast 169.254.255.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex,flow-control,energy-efficient-ethernet>)
    status: active
```

I hope these results help. I will supply more if needed.

Comment: You have 2 default routes on different network segments! You NEED to explain HOW the Pi is configured and what is connected to what.

Comment: NOTE setting static addresses is a poor idea (unless you have a good understanding of networking and have a reason).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address on Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi-os)

Comment: @Milliways Problem solved after I commented out the static address part. I thought it was included by default, and yet that part turned out to be the culprit. Great thanks for pointing this ("static address is unusual") out and sharing the informative link.